# Shorthand dictionary with named tuples in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift, tuples

It seems like you can't use named tuples in the shorthand notation of Dictionary. Is that so?
E.g.:

```
var dt = Dictionary<Int, (x:Double, y:Double)>()
var dtShort = [Int: (Double, Double)]()
var dtShortNamed = [Int: (x:Double, y:Double)]()
```

The first two lines work, the third triggers an error "Expected member name or constructor call after type name"
Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that it doesn't seem to work that way in Xcode 6 GM or Xcode 6.1 Beta 2.
It does work if you use a [`typealias`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_479) though:

```
typealias NamedTuple = (x:Double, y:Double)
var dtShortNamed = [Int: NamedTuple]()
```

But, in that case, you might as well just use your first example:

```
var dt = Dictionary<Int, (x:Double, y:Double)>()
```